# Cygwin + rsync: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cygwin, rsync

I'm trying to put a file from my local machine into EC2 and running into issues. I'm running on Windows and have my EC2 machine running and connected to, so I'm needing to use Cygwin to use Rsync. My current syntax is:

```
rsync -avz 'ssh -i /cygdrive/c/project/pemfilehere' /cygdrive/c/project/test.txt ec2-user@xxx.xx.xx.xxx:/var/
```

When I run this, I get:

```
Permision denied (publickey)
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226)     [sender=3.1.2]
```

I'm not entirely sure why the permission of the public key is denied. Any feedback on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try normal SSH to that instance first? If not try it and see if you are able to ssh use this  ssh -i 'mykey.pem'  ec2-user@xxx.xx.xx.xxx

Comment: So, on Git Bash, I am able to SSH to the instance. However, Cygwin doesn't let me, and says the permissions for the pen file are too open. "It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others. This private key will be ignored."

Do you know how I can fix this to allow it to be accepted?

Comment: Ok change the permission on the pem file to 600 and then try

Comment: Sorry, do you mind walking me through how to set it to 600?

Comment: Open the cygwig terminal type  cd /cygdrive/c/project and then chmod  600 key.pem

Comment: Thank you, so now it allows me to SSH into the instance on Cygwin. But when I do the command for rsync that I outlined in the original post, I still get the permission denied (public key) error.

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out! I added --progress -e right before the 'ssh -i pemfile' part, and it worked. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Ok so I am writing a answer please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your use case was your pem key was not having correct permission once you change the permission to 600 it will work correctly.